# What is the difference between the 2 Mongo queries below

Tags: nosql

Db.test.find({field1: true, field2: true})

Db.test.find({$and:[{field1: true},{field2:true}]})

I fired a count on both these queries and the count was same   Help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Those two queries are effectively the same.

According to the MongoDB documentation:

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma
>   separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and
>   operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be
>   specified in multiple expressions.

source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/